# Why is my call to expect not evaulated (Jest)?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am testing a WebSocket-based API and the message handler stalls at the call to 'expect' (it does not do the check). Not even the call to done gets evaluated.

```
describe('When a speed test is triggered', () => {
    test('Then AWS should send the result to the client', done => {
        ws.on('open', open = () => {
            ws.send(JSON.stringify({
                message: 'start-speed-test-rbsid',
                data: RBSID,
                platform: "android"
            }));
            ws.on('message', incoming = data => {
                data = JSON.parse(data)
                // this gets never evaluated
                expect(data.data.status).toBe('IN_PROGRESS')
                // execution never gets here
                done()
            });
        })
    })
```

I expected the call to 'expect' to be evaulated but it is not evaluated at all. The test stalls.

Comment: Are you using global variables `open`, `incoming` and `data` on purpose?

Comment: That should not matter?

Comment: Probably not, but it's still a bad practice. And in strict mode, it might even fail.

Comment: Good to know, thanks. Any ideas on why done is never called?